# Plot Window Hangs or is Empty in Python

Tags: python, macos, matplotlib, plot

I am having trouble with plots in a Jupyter Notebook in Python 3.5 on Mac OSX. The following code will hang when executed:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
#%matplotlib inline
myfig = plt.plot(range(5))
plt.show()
```

If I restart the kernel and un-comment '%matplotlib inline', I do get plots to work inline. However, I'd like to be plotting in a separate window.

If I insert the following code at the beginning:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')
```

then restart the kernel and run, the code will not hang, but nothing will be plotted, no window opened.
Details:
Mac Book Pro running OSX El Capitan
Anaconda Python 3.5 in a Jupyter Notebook
backend is "MacOSX".

Answer (score 0):

There is a [post on GitHub](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/3470) mentioning that using Qt4Agg as backend worked...
If it is not available (and if you can), you might want to try using Hombrew to install Python (instead of Anaconda), Qt and/or Gtk with which you'll be able to use matplotlib without problem.

Comment: I tried using QT4Agg as the backend (matplotlib.use('Qt4Agg')), but to no avail.

Comment: Ok, what was the behaviour? Did you try using python with homebrew?

Comment: The Qt4Agg backend caused hanging, just like the MacOSX backend. I did not try python with Homebrew, as I didn't want to risk messing up my current installation with any conflicts. In addition, I want to work in a notebook, so iPython seems like the way to go.